# How would one prove that satisfaction of closed formulas is valuation-independent? (In FOL)

Tags: logic, model-theory, predicate-logic, first-order-logic

Consider this proposition in first-order logic:

For any interpretation $I$, any closed formula $\phi$ and any two valuations $\rho$, $\sigma$.
$I\rho \models \phi \iff I\sigma \models \phi$

This is incredibly obvious yet i don't see how to prove it, the obvious induction doesn't really work since a formula is only closed when you have all the quantifiers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a preliminary result, like in Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0122384520) (2nd ed - 2001), page 86 :

> **THEOREM 22A** Assume that $s_1$ and $s_2$ are functions from $V$ [the set of *variables*] into $|\mathfrak A|$ [the *domain* of the structure] which agree at all variables (if any) that occur free in the wff $\varphi$.
>
> Then
>
> > $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi[s_1]$ iff $\mathfrak A \vDash \varphi[s_2]$.

The proof is by induction on the complexity of $\varphi$.

Then [page 87] :

> **COROLLARY 22B** For a *sentence* $\sigma$, either
>
> (a) $\mathfrak A$ satisfies $\sigma$ with every function $s$ from $V$ intto $|\mathfrak A|$, or
>
> (b) $\mathfrak A$ does not satisfy $\sigma$ with any such function.

Comment: Interesting. I did think of proving 22A. But my intuition somehow told me it didn't make sense.